# how to fix this function so it keeps detecting clicks?

Tags: javascript

This is my first question please go easy on me.

The issue I am having is I have a for each PHP loop to map out (populate) the divs based on how many customer profiles are in the database.

each div has the same class name, so... I use querySelectorAll('.customerBox') to create a NodeList with x amount of divs based on rows in the database.

With this, I am able to change styles based on the index of each item.

Below is a quick example of the script i'm running to do this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < customerBox1.length; i++) {
    (function(e){
        openCustBoxBtn1[e].onclick = function(){
            if(customerBox1[e].style.minWidth == '100%'){
                custCreationBox.style.display = 'flex';
                customerBox1[e].style.minWidth = '25%';
                customerBox1[e].style.minHeight = '50%';
            }
            if(customerBox1[e].style.minWidth < '100%'){
                custCreationBox.style.display = 'none';
                customerBox1[e].style.minWidth = '100%';
                customerBox1[e].style.minHeight = '100%';
            }
        }
    })(i);
}
```

This works perfectly fine the only issue is that the function only runs for two clicks on any element, so let's say there are three elements (.customerBox1)'s... I can click the button within the box to make it take up the 'full screen' then if I click that button again and element (.customerBox1) at the index of whichever you clicked has a minWidth of 100% it will shrink back to its original size, BUT after this that individual elements cannot be re-opened, but any other element at another index can.

gonna be honest I have a vague understanding of how this function works I found it here on stack overflow when searching how to run an onClick for querySelectorAll() at the index of the element you clicked.

Anything helps thank you, if you need more information please let me know. I tried to describe my issue as in-depth as possible.

Comment: Here is a visualization of the issue front end: https://youtu.be/ST_uLgKzA5s

Answer (score 0):

First of all this condition

```
customerBox1[e].style.minWidth < '100%'
```

It will not work as expected as you compare strings, you need map the value of minWidth to a number with parseInt(customerBox1[e].style.minWidth)

ex:

```
const minWidth = parseInt(customerBox1[e].style.minWidth)

        if(minWidth === 100){
            // code ...
        }
        if(minWidth < 100){
            // code ...
        }
```

Comment: first off Id like to thank you for teaching me something new. But sadly 100 alone is not read as a % value or pixel value its just 100, how could I use your method with parseInt but include the % after the 100. Or does the parsing ignore the % when reading the value?? when I console.log(minWidth) I get a return of NaN. Also I cant seem to upvote you because i have under 15 rep.

Comment: You are welcome, But the issue in the comparison itself, let's say as you said we know the if it's "pixel" or "%" or "vw" or "rem", what will you compare with? So it would be better to know the value with which prefix and compare it with the same prefix.